# Perl: check if environment variable is set

Tags: perl, exists

I have been using

`if(exists $ENV{VARIABLE_NAME} && defined $ENV{VARIABLE_NAME})` in several places my perl script.

I feel it clutters the code and so assigned its value to a variable.

```
$debug = $ENV{VARIABLE_NAME};
```

But, now I cant check for `exists` on a scalar value. Is there a way I can check exists for a scalar value?

Comment: @squiguy - I may have missed that question. I apologize for asking a similar sort of a question. Can I delete my question, in this case? I already got a couple of helpful responses.

Comment: If anything I thought it could help!  I edited to say *might* because it's hard to tell sometimes.  But in any case if you solved your problem then all is well.  Cheers.

Comment: You should assign a default value if you're not going to test for existance: `my $debug = $ENV{DEBUG} || 0;`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's no concept of `exists` for a scalar; for a hash, it tells you whether a given key appears in the hash (e.g., whether `keys %ENV` will contain it), but that's meaningless for a scalar.

But in the specific case of an environment variable, you don't need the `exists` test anyway: environment variables are always strings, so they are never `undef` unless they haven't been set — making `exists` equivalent to `defined` for them. So you can just write `if(defined $ENV{'VARIABLE_NAME'})` or `if(defined $debug)`.

Answer (score 7):

You're right that `exists` is meaningless for a scalar variable. But couldn't you just write `if(defined $ENV{VARIABLE_NAME})`? If it doesn't exist then `$ENV{VARIABLE_NAME}` will return `undef`.